# Google Analytics GA4 tracking package for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-4, .net-standard-2.0

It seems that I am unable to find any nuget package that supports Google Analytics - GA4 page and event tracking. Any one of you are aware of it? They are stop supporting using universal properties in a few weeks and I need to migrate to GA4 my UWP app. So a nuget package for .NET Standard 2.0 is much needed. Alternatives are welcome. Maybe Google Tag Manager, I am not sure.
Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

This page says you can use "Python (or ... any language of your choice) that can make this call" to send GA4 events: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/GA4_MP#4

Also check out this SO answer: [Sending Google Analytics events programatically from server side not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941663/sending-google-analytics-events-programatically-from-server-side-not-working)